# scheduling an informatica workflow with a customized frequency

Tags: admin, informatica-powercenter

Hello Dear Informatica admin/platform experts,

I have a workflow that i need to scheduled say Monday-Friday and Sunday. All the 6 days the job should at a specific time say 10 times in a day, but the timing is not uniform but at a predefined time say(9 AM, 11 AM, 1:30 PM etc), so the difference in the timing is not uniform. so we had 10 different scheduling workflows for each schedule/run that triggers a shell script that uses pmcmd command.

It looked a bit weird for me, so what i did was, have a single workflow that triggers the pmcmd shell script, and have a link between the start and the shell script where i specified a condition of the time and scheduled it to run monday-friday and sunday every 30 minutes.

So what happens is, it runs 48 times in a day but actually triggers the "actual" workflow only 10 times. and the remaining 38 times it just runs but does nothing.

one of my informatica admin colleague says that running this 38 times(which does actually nothing) consumes informatica resources. Though i was quite sure it does not, but as i am just an informatica developer and not an expert, thought of posting it here, to check whether it is really true?

Thanks.

Regards
Raghav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... it does consume some resources. Each time workflow starts, it does quite a few operations on the Repository. It also allocates some memory on Integration Service as well as creates log file for the Workflow. Even if there are no sessions executed at all.

So, there is an impact. Multiply that by the number of workflows, times the number of executions - and there might be a problem.

Not to mention there are some limitations regarding the number of Workflow being executed at the same time.

I don't know your platform and setup. But this look like a field for improvement indeed. A cron scheduler should help you a lot.

Comment: Dear Maciejg, Thanks a lot for your assistance and answer.Yes, true I did not mention complete details regarding the platform. Well the CPU is almost 90 to 95 % idle most of the time, and we do not have any problems of having multiple sessions running in parallel, as we have it set to quite a high number of 50 sessions. The main reason for me to go for a single scheduling workflow is that, we might soon go for 24 runs of frequency per day, and everytime we add a new frequency, we would have to add an equivalent scheduling workflow which would make the specific folder difficult to monitor.

Comment: Also forgot to mention, we actually use informatica scheduler for all the applications installed on the server. But i get your point that it does allocate memory and create logs, But considering that the job run for hardly a second or few seconds, how severe do you see it? We we have a very powerful server that is not at all used to it full, But i need to see how much of memory it is available which can be an important parameter for me to see.

Comment: You're welcome! 50 session in parallel is't a number I'd call 'high'. I've had single workflows evecuting over 200 sessions in parallel. A single workflow :) I also have had workflows running continously, every minute. So it has been creating all the logs, caches, etc. and completed in less then a minute and then run again. Seemed small, but had quite a big impact on the disks IO. I can't judge on your environment, you need to talk to the admins, probably. Perhaps there are other processes that you don't see? Anyway: scheduler in Informatica is a week spot. Look for improvements in this area.

Comment: Sure.I will get more platform details first from the admin and see how to go about it. Thanks again 